Does a homeomorphism preserve the open sets?
I would like to ask if the following statement is true and, if it is, how could we prove it:

Let $(X,\mathcal T), (X,\mathcal T')$ two homeomorphic topological spaces on the same non empty set $X$. Then $\mathcal T=\mathcal T'$.

If it is false, then how do we say that a metrizable topological space (i.e. a topological space homeomorphic to a metric space) preserves the topology (i.e. the $\mathcal T$-open and $\mathcal T _d$-open sets coincide, where $(X, \mathcal T), (X,d)$ the two spaces)?
Thanks a lot!

What means to be homeomorphic in terms of the existence of continuous maps? What can you say about the inverse image of an open subset by a continuous map?

The inverse image of an open set under a homeomorphism is an open set. Sorry, I do not understand the purpose of your question.

Your 2nd question is also unclear. A topological space $(X, \mathcal T)$ is said to be metrizable iff there is a distance $d$ on $X$ such that $ \mathcal T_d= \mathcal T$.

@SK_ It is almost an answer.

@Anne Bauval I give a definition from wiki (of course you can find it everywhere):
"a metrizable space is a topological space that is homeomorphic to a metric space."

@mathcounterexamples.net my problem is about the reason why of being the same open sets, i.e. $U\in \mathcal T \iff U\in \mathcal T'$. Maybe I am a little dizzy, but I cannot find it!

This definition ("topological space that is homeomorphic to a metric space") makes no sense. The correct definition is the sentence that follows it on Wikipedia, i.e. the one in my previous comment.

@SK_ You'll find the answer by yourself if you use my initial comment and refer to the definitions of an homeomorphism and continuity.

@mathcounterexamples.net Your comment was "almost an answer" to the question in the title, but the (1st) question in the body is not the same.

@SK_ The answer to your 1st question in the body is no. Find a counterexample on $X={0,1}$. And again, your 2nd question is unclear.

Does this answer your question? Do homeomorphisms preserve topological structure?

@julio_es_sui_glace Again, it does answer (by yes) the question in the title, but the answer to the (less usual) question in the body is no.

Yes indeed, for the second question I guess this is not really a question since both possible definition (the one by @AnneBauval and the one by you) give the same result: $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T}d$ for the definition of Anne, but in the second definition the "implicitly" defined metric is given by $\phi:X \to Y$ homeo and $d_X(x,x') = d_Y(\phi(x),\phi(x'))$ so once again by definition we would have $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T}{d_X}$

As for the first question, I think you should choose a less ambiguous title. Like "Prove or disprove: if $(X,\mathcal T)$ and $(X,\mathcal T')$ are homeomorphic, then $\mathcal T=\mathcal T'$"

In general if $\mathcal T$ is a topology which is a non-counterexample - so is invariant under permutations - then whenever $U$ is open and we have $|U| = |V|$ and $|X \setminus U| = |X \setminus V|$, then $V$ must also be open. So any topology in which openness depends on something more than cardinality must be a counterexample - this is almost all "nice" topologies. I believe it follows that the only non-counterexamples are the co-$\kappa$ spaces - eg the discrete space, the indiscrete space, the cofinite space, the cocountable space, etc.

On wiki 's definition of metrizability and the classical definition that @Anne quotes, I would say that, if there is a metric $d$ s.t. $\mathcal T=\mathcal T _d$, then the map $id:(X,\mathcal T)\to (X,d)$ is the desired homeomorphism. The problem is the converse: If there is a homeomorphism between two above spaces, is there also a metric that makes the topological space metrizable?

Such a metric was given in @julio's comment.

@julio_es_sui_glace I am a little confused: You introduce two metrics $d_X,d_Y$, but we have only one. The problem with wiki 's definition, which I note above, is the equivalence of metrizability of a t.s. $(X,\mathcal T)$  with homeomorphicity of $(X,\mathcal T)$ to a m.s. $(X,d)$.

@SK_ the metric $d_X$ was not introduced, I defined it using $d_Y$ and the homeo

Here is the counterexample on $X=\{0,1\}$ suggested in my earlier comment:
$$\mathcal T:=\{\varnothing,\{0\},X\}\ne\mathcal T':=\{\varnothing,\{1\},X\}$$
although the transposition $0\mapsto1,1\mapsto0$ is a homeomorphism between $(X,\mathcal T)$ and $(X,\mathcal T')$.

To answer your title question: Yes, a homemorphism does preserve open sets.  If $\newcommand{\T}{\mathcal{T}}(X,\T)$ and $(X',\T')$ are homeomorphic under $f : X \to X'$, then modulo this bijection $f$, $\T$ corresponds to $\T'$ — that is, $\T = \{ f^{-1}(U) \mid U \in \T' \}$, or equivalently, $\T' = \{ f(U) \mid U \in \T \}$.
However, this doesn’t imply the statement you give in the body, that if $(X,\T)$ and $(X,\T')$ are homeomorphic then $\T = \T'$.  Being homeomorphic means there’s a homeorphism $f : X \to X$, and modulo this bijection $f$, $\T$ corresponds to $\T'$ in the sense above.  But this doesn’t imply $\T = \T'$, unless $f$ is the identity map on $X$.
Other answers give nice finite counterexamples. Another example, natural and fairly intuitive, is $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\R$ with the upper or lower interval topologies (generated by intervals $(x,\infty)$ for the upper case, or alternatively $(-\infty,x)$ for the lower). These are not the same topology — but the only difference is a reversal of the order, so they’re homeomorphic to each other via the order-reversal map $x \mapsto -x$.

Let $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and let $\mathcal T = \{ \emptyset, \{1\}, \{2,3\}, X\}$ and $\mathcal T' = \{ \emptyset, \{2\}, \{1,3\}, X\}$. These spaces are homeomorphic via the map $1 \mapsto 2, 2 \mapsto 1, 3 \mapsto 3$ but $\mathcal T \neq \mathcal T'$.

An easy counterexample with metric spaces: for $a\in\mathbb{R}$, define the following metric
$$
d_a(x,y)=\begin{cases} \min\{|x-y|,1\} & x\ne a,y\ne a \\[1ex] 1 & x=a,y\ne a \\[1ex] 1 & x\ne a,y=a \\[1ex] 0 & x=y=a \end{cases}
$$
The map $f\colon(\mathbb{R},d_0)\to (\mathbb{R},d_1)$ defined by $f(x)=x+1$ is a homeomorphism.
The set $\{0\}$ is open for the topology induced by $d_0$, but it isn't open for the topology induced by $d_1$.

I would like to summarize somehow.
Suppose the topological spaces $(X,\mathcal T),(Y,\mathcal T')$, where $X,Y$ nonempty sets. If they are homeomorphic, i.e. there exists a bicontinuous map $\phi:(X,\mathcal T)\to(Y,\mathcal T')$, then the open sets are preserved:
We have $G\in \mathcal T'\implies \phi^{-1}(G):=U\in \mathcal T\implies G=\phi (U)\in \mathcal T'$, for $\phi$ is a homeomorphism, thus it is an open map and its inverse is an open map too. Hence $\mathcal T'=\{\phi (U)|U\in \mathcal T\}$. Similarly $\mathcal T=\{\phi^{-1}(V)|V\in \mathcal T'\}$.
Let $(X,\mathcal T)\simeq (X, \mathcal T')$. These homeomorphic topological spaces on the same underlying set $X$ do not need to share the same topology (i.e. $\mathcal T=\mathcal T'$). As a counterexample we can consider $\mathcal T, \mathcal T'$ as the Sierpiński topologies with their singleton different.
Finally, if $(X, \mathcal T)$ is metrizable, i.e. there is a metric $d:X^2\to \Bbb R$ such that $\mathcal T=\mathcal T_d$, then $(X, \mathcal T),(X,\mathcal T_d)$ are homeomorphic under the identity map $\rm id_X$$:X\to X$. Finally, if $(X, \mathcal T)\simeq (X,\mathcal T_d)$ for some metric $d:X^2\to\Bbb R$, then the topological space is metrizable:
Consider the metric $\rho (x,y):=d(\phi(x), \phi(y))$ for $x,y\in X$. Use the equality $\phi (B_{\rho}(x,\epsilon))=B_d(\phi (x), \epsilon)$ to prove that $U\in \mathcal T_{\rho}\iff U\in \mathcal T$.

This summary looks almost right. But I think that if $(X, \mathcal T)$ is homeomorphic to $(X, \mathcal T_d)$ for some metric topology $\mathcal T_d$, then it is necessarily the case that $\mathcal T$ is equal to the metric topology $\mathcal T_{d'}$ for some metric $d'$. The point is that you "transport" $d$ along the earlier homeomorphism. That's the content of this comment. The Sierpinski space isn't homeomorphic to any metric topology because it's not Hausdorff.

You are right about the second counterexample (Sierpiński space isn' t metrizable); it is my fault and I am going to remove it.
